# add opencv to indigo

Tags: opencv, opencv2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Opencv packages aren't built in the ROS Indigo anymore. So what should I do if I want to add opencv2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185105/add-opencv-to-indigo/) by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that for compatibility with Hydro and general simplicity it is recommended to use cv_bridge as a dependency to pull in opencv for Indigo packages (a bit hacky though, as this pulls in other related packages). See [discussion on github](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4722) and [Indigo migration guide on OpenCV](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#OpenCV).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-07-09**:
Given the OP asks about Indigo, I think this looks more appropriate ROS-way and should be chosen as the answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install opencv by yourself on your computer, the easiest way is to clone this to your computer
https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV

```
git clone https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV.git
```

Then run the ubuntu/opencv_install.sh

Now in your ros package:

In the manifest.xml add this line

```
<rosdep name="opencv2"/>
```

you also need to include these lines in your CMakeFiles.txt

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(your_cpp_node ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

for linking the libraries to the nodes written in c++.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) on 2014-07-07**:
Thanks for your reply. I do the same and add the lines except the last line (target_link_libraries) since the package is written in python. The package is built correctly but I get following error when using roslaunch for running it:  cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv(data, "bgr8")
AttributeError: CvBridge instance has no attribute 'imgmsg_to_cv'

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-07-07**:
This is not the right way to do it -- the opencv2 rosdep will slowly be going away, replaced by the libopencv-dev rosdep which uses the system OpenCV rather than the one built for ROS. On ubuntu, all you should have to do is "sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev".

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-07-07**:
Further, if you are using debians for cv_bridge, etc, you should almost certainly be using debians for OpenCV.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-07**:
Thanks for the update @fergs

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-08-01**:
@fergs sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev caused me a lot of troubles, deleting it and compiling OpenCV by myself solved them

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-22**:
Hi, I'm stuck in a similar situation. My node is a Python node, and not a CPP node. In this case, how do I proceed with target link libraries?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-04-23**:
@voladoddi, no need to link, in your python script just write "import cv2"

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-23**:
Yes, thanks! it was already there I just needed to remove the link libraries line entirely. It makes sense now.

**Comment by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on 2015-10-26**:
When I run opencv_install.sh I get: Please define version before calling opencv_install.sh or use a wrapper like opencv_latest.sh  How do I install opencv2?

**Comment by [ML](https://answers.ros.org/users/28426/ml/) on 2016-11-03**:
Thanks stefan this worked for me.
I needed to rebuild opencv2 from source because somehow i got an error when using cv::imshow() (error message: /home/user/Downloads/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+

**Comment by [bhanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22691/bhanu/) on 2017-04-14**:
I cannot find CMakeFiles.txt in any directory, could anyone help me finding it or do I have to create one ?